# Pattern Matching or RegEx Man Page in linux/unix?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I've got an exam and I'm only allowed to use the man pages. I'm wondering how I can find the pattern matching details in the man pages?

Something similar to this info:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: Just curious: what marvelous course is it that includes regexes (as opposed to automata), and which refers you to man pages? Sounds fun!

Comment: Would `apropos` and `info` be disallowed too? In general get the basic man page that relates, e.g. awk (or gawk), grep, sed, perlre etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**for regexes in sed and grep and most standard Unix tools**

`man 7 regex` tells you about regexes used in `sed`, `grep`, and most standard tools.

See the man page for the tool itself as well, because there might be some exceptions.

**for regexes in other tools**

Many tools that didn't originally come with Unix have their own syntax.

For example, for `perl` look at `man perlre` and for `vim` type `:help pattern` from inside vim.

**for shell patterns**

Also known as wildcards or globs.

`man bash` then type `/Pathname Expansion<Enter>`.

Or better yet, if `info` is installed, `info bash` will get you exactly the same information as the link in your question.

You can drill down to the section manually, or get there directly by running:

```
info bash 'Basic Shell Features' 'Shell Expansions' 'Filename Expansion' 'Pattern Matching'
```

**a final tip**

You can try searching for man pages by running:

```
man -k <search term>
```

For example:

```
$ man -k regex
re_comp (3)          - BSD regex functions
re_exec (3)          - BSD regex functions
regcomp (3)          - POSIX regex functions
regerror (3)         - POSIX regex functions
regex (3)            - POSIX regex functions
regex (7)            - POSIX.2 regular expressions
regexec (3)          - POSIX regex functions
regexp_table (5)     - format of Postfix regular expression tables
regfree (3)          - POSIX regex functions
```

Comment: Added a note about `man -k`.  That should help if you can't find the docs for some other command or file format.

Comment: `apropos` and `info` are also useful for finding references.

Comment: Yes, `apropos` == `man -k`.  And of course, if `info bash` works, then `info <something else you want to understand>` might work too.

Comment: And `info --apropos <search term>` to search all the `info` docs.

Answer (score 1):

Would `man grep` do?

Or you could always, you know, actually learn regexp.

Comment: @Wes: yeah...regex has quite a steep learning curve. If you think you're going to be able to look at the manual on test day and understand it all...lol good luck on that count. Pray the questions are super basic like "what does + mean?"

Comment: Haha yeah, I'm fairly good with regex just would like knowing it was in the man pages for reference. Man Grep doesn't carry the pattern matching ? * [] and whatnot, but I guess I can memorize them.

Comment: Actually, the `grep` man page should have some details.  Type `/REGULAR EXPRESSIONS` to see that section.

Answer (score 0):

try man find and man grep, or the more robust command, info grep, info find. Depending on the os they have the full reg exp in them. Or find the man page for reg exp.